# Assets.xcassets unlinked from project in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcasset

I am new to Swift. While creating project I accidentally deleted the `Assets.xcasset` file. I retrieved it from trash and imported it to project. Now my problem is that images are not getting attached to the file. while running app it crashes with below error -

`signal SIGABRT error {Could not load the "redeem" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier } because images are not getting attached.`

Comment: The images probably got unlinked from your xib/storyboard. Edit it to remove & replace the images used there.

Comment: Add it back. File → Add Files to "YourProject" → select Assets.xcasset

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: did you click on target member ship?. check link http://screencast.com/t/MKt4rw8KoI